# Eclipse RCP: Display.getDefault().asyncExec waits more than 4000ms to execute

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

I am using `TreeViewer` and creating Job to refresh `Treeview` that is added 4k - 5k nodes. In Refresh Job, I call `Display.getDefault().asyncExec` to execute `getTreeViewer().refresh()`  method. However, I have faced the problem that `getTreeViewer().refresh()` has to wait 4000ms or more than that to run. This is in Ubuntu and Windows has to wait more than 30000ms.

i don't know why it has to wait for long time to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncExec` runs as soon as possible on the SWT User Interface thread. So if it is being delayed something else must be using that thread. Since you have a large tree it is probably the `TreeViewer` building the tree that is causing the delay (unless you are running something that take a long time in the UI thread).

For a large tree you may need to look at creating the tree with the `SWT.VIRTUAL` style and use a `ILazyTreeContentProvider` content provider.